Let's curate the list of non-series tags and correctly apply them to all associated questions
Generally speaking, the tags on the main site are divided into two categories: the series tags and the non-series tags.
The series tags, barring a few cases like travel and fate-series, are usually self-explanatory and self-contained, two important properties that enable the effective use of tags.
They naturally grow in numbers with each passing season, and require just one or two policies or feature implementations* to keep them from sprawling.
The non-series tags, on the other hand, have been a source of contention since the inception of this site.
There have been past attempts to keep these in check, and it is long overdue for another round of housekeeping.
The first order of business is to have a list of the non-series tags available so we can go over them.
This is harder than it looks because Stack Exchange does not provide a way to distinguish between even two categories of tags on its main sites, so I had to dig up an old post and update the list by means of enumeration.
The table below is the list of non-series tags on Anime.SE as of October 8, 2024 (if I have missed something, please let me know):



TagType
TagName
TagSynonyms
QuestionsTagged




characters
domo-kun

1


characters
hatsune-miku

4


characters
os-tan

2


characters
super-sonico

2


companies
anime-planet

1


companies
crunchyroll

19


companies
funimation

5


companies
gainax

1


companies
key

2


companies
kyoto-animation

2


companies
madhouse

1


companies
myanimelist

4


companies
netflix

2


companies
pixiv

1


companies
sentai-filmworks

1


companies
studio-ghibli

8


companies
type-moon

10


conventions
anime-expo

1


conventions
comiket

6


fandom
amv

5


fandom
conventions

12


fandom
cosplay

10


fandom
doujinshi

14


fandom
itasha

3


fandom
merchandise

110


general
crossovers

4


general
culture

201


general
japanese-language

270


general
light-novel-site

1


general
meme

29


general
music
insert-songs, ost, soundtrack
559


general
panel-arrangement

4


general
quotes

1


general
resources
resource-request
98


general
sign-language

6


general
streaming-sites

20


general
symbolism

44


general
terminology

83


general
theme-song
ending-theme, opening-theme, theme-music
71


general
tourism

17


general
tropes

288


industries
anime-history

165


industries
anime-industry

2


industries
anime-production
filler, fillers
460


industries
censorship

21


industries
copyright

17


industries
events

1


industries
game-history

5


industries
law

4


industries
licensing

14


industries
light-novel-history

4


industries
light-novel-production

17


industries
live-action-production

4


industries
localization

2


industries
manga-history

49


industries
mangaka

36


industries
manga-production

162


industries
promotional-videos

1


industries
visual-novel-production

6


industries
voice-acting
seiyuu
46


other-reified
anime-no-chikara

1


other-reified
vocaloid

12


people
aimer

1


people
barasui

1


people
claris

1


people
hayao-miyazaki

13


people
hideaki-anno

2


people
hiroyuki-sawano

2


people
jun-maeda

1


people
kajiura-yuki

1


people
kazuki-nakashima

1


people
kazuki-takahashi

1


people
ken-akamatsu

2


people
kouji-seo

2


people
maaya-sakamoto

1


people
makoto-shinkai

3


people
mamiko-noto

1


people
mamoru-hosoda

1


people
mamoru-oshii

1


people
masamune-shirow

1


people
sachika-misawa

1


people
shun-saeki

1


publications
ribon

1


publications
shonen-jump

9


regions
australia

1


regions
england

1


regions
europe

3


regions
germany

1


regions
greece

1


regions
india

8


regions
japan

31


regions
north-korea
dprk
1


regions
singapore

1


regions
spain

1


regions
united-states

5


special
identification-request

27


special
retag
anime-retag, manga-retag
1



We should start by discussing if certain whole classes of tags should be kept or eliminated.
For example, the country tags, or tags of the regions type in the table above, have been trial run for almost ten years now.
Do we want them or not?
When making suggestions to tag changes, i.e. adding to, removing, renaming or synonymizing the tags listed in the table, it is helpful to base them on Logan's three principles (with my annotations in bold):

[self-contained] a tag should be something that someone could legitimately be an expert on,
[self-explanatory] tags should not be prone to misuse, and
[self-sufficient] we should not have two tags with identical or nearly identical scopes.

Principle 1 is tied to tag badges, and principles 2 and 3 directly affect searching by tags and the watched and ignored tags functionality.
Another very important consideration to take is that tag merging can be done quickly, but undoing a tag merge can be cumbersome.
This has been discussed in the past when there were some voices calling for a merge of the various *-history tags under an all-encompassing history tag.
I have also created a SEDE query to aid in finding questions potentially missing some non-series tags, which is also in the list of queries collected in the ongoing cleanup task meta post.
Very roughly speaking, the lower the QuestionsTagged / TagSuggestedCount ratio is, the likelier the tag is problematic, unless it is skewed by false positives.
Lastly, for the non-series tags that make it to the final stage of the curation process, we should complete and refine their tag excerpts for the finishing touch.
The positive outcomes of this community effort that I see are twofold:

Lower the likelihood of mistagging by users, reducing noise and moderation effort.
Improve question discoverability and alignment to subject experts through better tags.

I will leave any follow-up coordination to the moderators for they would want to see this project to its completion.

* The Collectives feature over at Stack Overflow should be able to support our use cases pretty well with a few tweaks.
It already supports associating tags under a collective, and if it further allows associating a collective under another collective and for a collective to be watched or ignored just like a tag, we could for example map out the following relations for TYPE-MOON's franchises:

nasuverse (collective and metaseries tag)

the-garden-of-sinners
tsukihime
melty-blood
fate-series (collective and metaseries tag)

fate-stay-night
fate-hollow-ataraxia
fate-zero
fate-kaleid-liner-prisma-illya
fate-extra
fate-apocrypha
fate-strange-fake
fate-grand-order


witch-on-the-holy-night
carnival-phantasm



Whenever a new series tag is added to a collective, the users who have the collective on watch (or ignore) would automatically receive (or not receive) notifications for questions tagged by this newly associated tag.
Maintaining highly related series tags would also become easier as we have a customized view of all tag associations within a collective.


As per this meta, it seemed appropriate to merge filler as it was typically part of some decision related (at least a decision by those in charge) to production. If you're not inclined to agree with the decision, any suggestions to alternatives are welcome. I would agree that we need to have a review of generic named tags for series. As per the [tag: dogs] I created one for the series (Dogs: Bullets and Carnage) and merged that tag into it.

There similar issues with many one off series like [tag:aegis] and some for more popular series like [tag:air]. We never really got around to how to deal with series with the same name but different authors. There are also some series name still in Japanese that could be synonymized with their appropriate English names, where appropriate, but that's a separate topic.

@кяαzєя For series with the same name but different authors, a quick glance at Stack Overflow suggests a pragmatic approach. For example, there is the D programming language like C++ and one used in DTrace; the more general, popular and individual one (the former) is picked.

I was considering something like that for the less popular series by appending the author name, but it's typically a rare case, usually with manga, like <series-name>-<author name>

@кяαzєя I just made a big update, please have a look. We could start by looking at the tags with < 10 tagged questions, the majority out of a total of 97 tags. Definitely manageable even for 1 person to cover say 10 tags in a year, could definitely go for more. I was thinking of community answers by tag type and bullets lists as they're easier to edit than tables. Do you want me to write another post to collect consensus and leave this one for discussion only, or just go ahead with it in one post?

@кяαzєя Re: series with the same name or is a generic vocab, I don't know how to deal with it either, nothing optimal comes to mind. Maybe that is a lesson to not use the names as IDs in a database design? Then there is the UI/UX problem of how to prevent users from choosing the wrong tags if there are multiple tags with the same name. Tag excerpts help with that, displaying a database thumbnail might be better. There are a lot of things to consider if SE were to have a redesign.

the simplest way could be to add -anime or -manga (or -short for short oneshot anime) to the end of the name if we don't use the author's name or penname. For short form content like the DAOKO short featuring Teddyloid genetically titled "Girl" we tagged it as "girl-daoko". But there are cases where there might not be a singular entity to credit. Once such example we currently have is the [tag:shelter] animated short. We could use the studio, the director, or the writer. But it would be easier to call it "shelter-short" IMO. If we need to distinguish manga oneshots, we can in a similar way.

I would agree that cleanup is overdue.
If we're going to do this, I'd like to suggest a type of queue system to manage and keep track of things.
Monthly or quarterly, we can have a meta post with tags or tasks related to tags that need cleanup, review, revision, etc.
We could break these up into manageable chunks so they don't take up to much time and can be collaborated with on an as needed basis. For example, we can review tags alphabetical and give priority to the more recent series.
How it would work is a meta post (i.e. The question) would serve to collect all the tasks that should be done. Each task would be an answer and have a title and description explaining task (general description of what needs to be done and the acceptance criteria, and any artifacts like queries to help describe or assist with the task, where applicable) like [meta-tag: status-review] [meta-tag: status-pending] [meta-tag: status completed] to indicate the activity status for those working on it. Users can comment on an answer to let folks know they are working on it.
Once a task is done it can be reviewed by the one that posted it to see if it fulfilled the criteria. Tasks that are incomplete could carry over to the next month or quarter if they are popular enough (maybe 3-4 or higher can be considered "popular").
The suggested cleanup queue post would likely be featured on our meta as such to make people aware of ongoing stuff on meta for the few that peruse it. This should give some better transparency and let us better track progress, as things on meta can fall off pretty easily.
Where possible the moderators, or at least myself, will do what we can to keep things in order (check up on status, marks tasks as done/inactive) or pick up less popular but notable tasks.
For now, lets focus on the main tags and then review synonyms as needed in the future. At worst such a cleanup post will be something for the moderators to be aware of of things on the site that need attention for them to look into

Monthly is overkill. The mods could do it in the year in review post, running over every query in senshin's ongoing cleanup task post detailing how the numbers have improved compared to the previous year. I think that is the best place to announce it, and the timeframe is more maintainable and expected. Of course you could do quarterly update, but that should be more optional.

Timeframe depends on the amount of cleanup needed. Anime changes by quarter so I thought it would be good to line it up with the change of shows. Starting out it will probably be slow so a longer timeframe might be appropriate.

For series tags, sure, a quarterly review is maybe more timely, but let's keep the discussion focused on the non-series tags, which don't/shouldn't change much over time. And also because I assume any problem with a series' tagging should be caught more quickly by users following the series (exceptions are for big franchises and how to break it up and use the most appropriately scoped one, or those posts using some anime as examples but aren't really about those anime).
